# How to get 14 days prior to the given date avoiding holidays

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my system ,the due date of the bill must be 14 days after the issued date.
I have due date and I want to know issued date .
I have to calculate :

```
issued date = 14 days prior to the due date
```

but  **14 days must be business days ,not holidays.**
Holidays is stored in a table 'tblHolidayMaster' like this,

> > Date                   Description
> >     
> > 2012/05/13         Mother's
> >     Day
> > 2012/06/02         Saturnday
> > 2012/12/25         Christmas

How can I calculate the issued date avoiding holidays?
Thank you for all of your interests and replies.

Comment: I selected all of the holidays from the table and calculate to get issued date.Is there a more simple solution ??

Comment: no, your soution is right. theres no formula for holidays.

Comment: With My Solution, I have to select all datas ,even the old datas about 2 years ,3 years old :(

Comment: It would be better (rather than just having a holiday table) to have a calendar table (one example [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2010/07/19/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions.aspx)). Over the long term, it makes writing many date-related queries like this easier.

Comment: Is the given date guaranteed to be a business day? If not, how do you want to treat non holiday target dates?

Comment: @CodeInChaos given date can be holiday.Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @NyeinNyeinChanChan: please check my answer, it should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would calculate the Date using a function like the one below (which i use)

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int days)
 {
    if (days == 0) return date;

   if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
   {
    date = date.AddDays(2);
    days -= 1;
  }
  else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
  {
    date = date.AddDays(1);
    days -= 1;
  } 



 date = date.AddDays(days / 5 * 7);
 int extraDays = days % 5;

 if ((int)date.DayOfWeek + extraDays > 5)
 {
    extraDays += 2;
 }

int extraDaysForHolidays =-1;
//Load holidays from DB into list
List<DateTime> dates = GetHolidays();

while(extraDaysForHolidays !=0)
{

 var days =  dates.Where(x => x >= date  && x <= date.AddDays(extraDays)).Count;
 extraDaysForHolidays =days;
 extraDays+=days;  
}


return date.AddDays(extraDays);
```

}

Haven't tested the ast section that does the holidays

Comment: I wouldn't do inline SQL like that. I'd rather put the dates into a list(ordered by date) and iterate over it once.

Comment: I think your holiday code doesn't interact with weekends correctly.

Comment: It shouldnt matter @chaos as there wont be a holiday on a weekend

Comment: @CodeInChaos Putting the dates into a list requires loading the complete table into memory. Usually that's not a problem, but sometimes it is. (But please, if you require separate queries like that, use parameters.)

Comment: @Ketchup What happens when the result would be a friday, except it's a holiday? You appear to skip over the friday and return a saturday.

Comment: I calculate the weekends first, then calculate the holidays after. So even if it is a holiday it will be picked up at the end

Comment: The holyday code has several bugs: 1) If at least one holiday is in the interval, the loop won't terminate (barring int overflow) 2) A holiday adjacent to a weekend can push the return value into the weekend. 3) Holidays can fall on the weekend. At least in Germany. Easter sunday for example.

Comment: The OP also wants to subtract from a given date, you code doesn't handle `days<0`.

Answer (score 2):

I went with the straight forward looping solution, so it will be slow for long intervals. But for short intervals like 14 days, it should be quite fast.

You need to pass in the holidays in the constructor. An instance of `BusinessDays` is immutable and can be reused. In practice you probably will use an IoC singleton or a similar construct to get it.

`AddBusinessDays` throws an `ArgumentException` if the start date is a non business day, since you didn't specify how to treat that case. In particular `AddBusinessDays(0)` on a non business day would have strange properties otherwise. It'd either break time reversal symmetry, or return a non business day.

```
public class BusinessDays
{
    private HashSet<DateTime> holidaySet;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<DayOfWeek> WeekendDays{get; private set;}

    public BusinessDays(IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> weekendDays)
    {
        WeekendDays = new ReadOnlyCollection<DayOfWeek>(weekendDays.Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray());
        if(holidays.Any(d => d != d.Date))
            throw new ArgumentException("holidays", "A date must have time set to midnight");
        holidaySet = new HashSet<DateTime>(holidays);
    }

    public BusinessDays(IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays)
        :this(holidays, new[]{DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday})
    {
    }

    public bool IsWeekend(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        return WeekendDays.Contains(dayOfWeek);
    }

    public bool IsWeekend(DateTime date)
    {
        return IsWeekend(date.DayOfWeek);
    }

    public bool IsHoliday(DateTime date)
    {
        return holidaySet.Contains(date.Date);
    }

    public bool IsBusinessDay(DateTime date)
    {
        return !IsWeekend(date) && !IsHoliday(date);
    }

    public DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int days)
    {
        if(!IsBusinessDay(date))
            throw new ArgumentException("date", "date bust be a business day");
        int sign = Math.Sign(days);
        while(days != 0)
        {
            do
            {
              date.AddDays(sign);
            } while(!IsBusinessDay(date));
            days -= sign;
        }
        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is what you required. It is simple and I have tested it and it is working... And it is not a bad approach to write a function or SP in databases rather to write the complex code in C#... (change column name of date as in your db.)

Make it function or SP as what you want.

**Note:** Comment the check of 'Saturday' and 'Sunday'. If it is already added in your table reocrds.

```
declare @NextWorkingDate datetime
declare @CurrentDate datetime
set @CurrentDate = GETDATE()
set @NextWorkingDate = @CurrentDate 
declare @i int = 0
While(@i < 14)
Begin
    if(((select COUNT(*) from dbo.tblHolidayMaster where convert(varchar(10),[Date],101) like convert(varchar(10),@NextWorkingDate,101)) > 0) OR DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@NextWorkingDate) = 'Saturday' OR DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@NextWorkingDate) = 'Sunday')
    Begin
        print 'a '  
        print @NextWorkingDate
        set @NextWorkingDate = @NextWorkingDate + 1
        CONTINUE
    End
    else
    Begin
        print  'b ' 
        print @NextWorkingDate
        set @NextWorkingDate = @NextWorkingDate + 1
        set @i = @i + 1
        CONTINUE
    End
End
print @NextWorkingDate
```

Answer (score 1):

I calculate the issued date avoid your holiday from your table 'tblHolidayMaster' only.

```
 int addDay = -14;
  DateTime dtInputDay = System.DateTime.Now;//Your input day
  DateTime dtResultDate = new DateTime();
  dtResultDate = dtInputDay.AddDays(addDay);
  bool result = false;
  string strExpression;
  DataView haveHoliday;
  while (!result) {
      strExpression = "Date >='" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtResultDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) + "' and Date <='" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtInputDay.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) + "'";
      haveHoliday = new DataView(tblHolidayMaster);
      haveHoliday.RowFilter = strExpression;
      if (haveHoliday.Count == 0) {          
        result = true;
      } else {
          addDay = -(haveHoliday.Count);
          dtInputDay = dtResultDate.AddDays(-1);
          dtResultDate = dtResultDate.AddDays(addDay);
      }
  }
```

Your issued date is dtResultDate

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tirthacs/difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends/